# Помогите сформировать JQL-запрос

Tags: jira

Помогите сформировать JQL-запрос следующего вида: как пользователь, я хочу увидеть все задачи определенного проекта N, у которых есть связанные (через is contained in ) задачи с типом "Ошибка"